# Facebook android sdk 4.6.0 jar not found

Tags: android

> I have imported facebook android sdk4.6.0 but its giving me the following error. How to resolve this error. Please help me.

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
```

> Artifact 'facebook-android-sdk.jar (com.facebook.android:facebook-android-    sdk:4.6.0)' not found.
>     Searched in the following locations:
>         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/facebook/android/facebook-android-   sdk/4.6.0/facebook-android-sdk-4.6.0.jar

Answer (score 0):

To use Facebook SDK in your project, you have to add it as a build dependency and import it. Follow these steps:

**When you create a new project** in Android Studio, be sure that the "Minimum SDK" is API 15 (Android 4.0.3) or higher

**After you create a new project**, open your app, then open your "/app/build.gradle" and add:

- below buildToolsVersion "XX.X.X"

`repositories {
     mavenCentral()
 }`

- in your dependecies

`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'`

Build your project clicking on "Tools > Android > Sync project".

Your build.gradle will be something like that:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "bla.bla.bla"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        encoding "UTF-8"
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
}
```

More info in the **getting started**: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started